# Geth is eating up my CPU

Tags: go-ethereum

Within seconds of starting the console, my machine goes into overdrive with the fan kicking in and everything. How can I tell geth to take it easy?

I am running a quad core i5-3317U CPU @ 1.70GHz via Ubuntu.

Comment: what command do you use to start running the console?
could it be that you are telling it to mine instead of sync? if cpu is going into overdrive it seems to me that it is mining.

Comment: How much RAM your machine has?

Answer (score 1):

If you're mining it is likely your machine will heat up.  There isn't really a slow-down button on computers.  But, you can pass `--minerthreads=1` to minimally mine.

Answer (score 0):

From the command line documentation of geth:

```
PERFORMANCE TUNING OPTIONS:

--cache value 
Megabytes of memory 
allocated to internal caching (min 
16MB / database forced) (default:128)
```